# Как вставить bxslider в popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, bxslider

Друзья, как правильно вставить bxslider в popup?

Я думаю многие сталкивались уже с данной проблемой, так что, обойдемся без скринов :)

Я так понимаю проблема в этой строчке:

```
<div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 0px;">
```

**Вопрос:** как это исправить?

Вот код самого слайдера:

```
$('.popup_slider ul').bxSlider({ nextText:'', prevText:'', minSlides: 3, maxSlides: 3, slideWidth: 121, speed: 500, controls: true, pager: false });
```

Comment: Что-то ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема со стилями. У Вас слайдер обсчитывает в 0 высоту. ПО всей вероятности что-то не так со слайдами. Если делается не на локале, то дайте ссылку.

Answer (score 0):

Слайдер инициализирует высоту по имеющимся высотам слайдов, т. е. когда происходит инициализация, у слайдов высота 0 пикселей, поскольку обрамляющий их попап обычно имеет `display: none`.

**Решение:** инициализировать слайдер после появления попапа, использовать коллбек, а после закрытия слайдер деинициализировать. Например, при использовании плагина для попапов bPopup:

```
var slider;

$('.popup').bPopup({
  onOpen: function() {
    slider = $('.slider').bxSlider();
  },
  onClose: function() {
   slider.destroySlider();
  }
});
```